# Need help making code for equilateral triangle in java work

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

For some reason only the odd numbered lines are spacing correctly. Can someone please explain this? Here is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Triangle {


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i, j, k1;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the length of the side of your equilateral triangle: ");
        int side = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the character you want your triangle filled with: ");
        char fill = in.next().charAt(0);
        while (side<=0 || side>50){
            System.out.print("Please enter a length between 1 and 50: ");
            side = in.nextInt();
            break;
        }
        for(i=1; i<=side;i++){
            for (k1=0; k1 < (side-i/2);k1++){
                System.out.print("\t");
            }
            for(j=1;j<=i;j++){
                System.out.print(fill + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println('\n');
        }
        in.close();
    }
}
```

This is my outcome:
    Enter the length of the side of your equilateral triangle: 
    5
    Enter the character you want your triangle filled with: 
    *

```
                *   

            *   *   

            *   *   *   

        *   *   *   *   

        *   *   *   *   *
```

I want this:

```
    # 
   # # 
  # # # 
 # # # # 
# # # # #
```

Comment: What are you getting, and what are you expecting?

Comment: Unrelated: What's the point of a `while` loop with an unconditional `break`?

Comment: This is my first java class so I assumed the break would continue the rest of my code after user entered a correct number

Comment: Without the `break`, the loop will keep looping until a valid number is entered, then exit the loop. With the `break`, the loop exits immediately, even if new number is invalid.

Comment: Ok. I am expecting a triangle that is properly spaced on all lines not just the odd numbered ones.

Comment: You added the actual output. What is the desired output? What is your goal? Your requirement?

Comment: To get the output you just added to the question, you can either follow all 3 instructions in my answer, or use the code in ɐuıɥɔɐɯ's answer. Both will give you that **exact** output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add this and change /t to 4 spaces:

```
if(i%2 ==0 && j ==1){
     System.out.print("  "); // two spaces
}
```

---

Full code

```
    for(i=1; i<=side;i++){

        for (k1=0; k1 < (side-i/2);k1++){
            System.out.print("    ");
        }
        for(j=1;j<=i;j++){

            if(i%2 ==0 && j ==1){
                System.out.print("  ");
            }
            System.out.print(fill + "    ");
        }
        System.out.println('\n');
    }
```

The reason is because every even line needs to start with a little offset since it has to be in the middle of the filler character and i get this

```
                                *    

                              *    *    

                            *    *    *    

                          *    *    *    *    

                        *    *    *    *    *    

                      *    *    *    *    *    *    

                    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    

                  *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    

                *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *
```

Comment: This! Thank you so much!

Comment: This doesn't works as expected...and I'm not arguing due to the fact you didn't accept what I answered. Just try with a side of length `1`, `2`, `3`...`N` and you'll see the "glitch'

Comment: A bit lopsided. Maybe 3 spaces would be better than 4.

Comment: Removed i==1 check, maybe that was a bit extra

Comment: You got it...that's my point, the "spaces" must be computed dynamically depending on the `side` length

Comment: yes, spacing will improve it but thats just eye candy :)

Comment: @BasitAnwer LOL, if spacing is "just eye candy", then the original code is good. It's just the "eye candy" indenting spaces that are off, right?

Comment: Would the code still work if User input different symbols like '%' or '&'? It's turning out a bit skewed for me

Comment: Depends on the font. What font are you using ? Is it 'courier' ?

Comment: @HelenaGray The "bit skewed" effect is the "lopsided" I was alluding to 7 comments up.

Comment: @Andreas I appreciate your humour but what i meant was to solve OPs problem :)

Comment: How do I make it dynamic to the side length without making the code very complicated?

Comment: Fixing the space problem (Which @Andreas identiified) and i'll try to answer  your comment as well

Comment: Thought over it, fixing the spacing problem will make it a little more complicated. The better way to do would be to identify the position of the first character then reference placement of other characters accordingly. Right now your reference is x = 0

Answer (score 1):

You haven't stated the desired outcome, but remove the `/2` might do the trick.

Maybe replace both `\t` with a space.

Remove the `'\n'` from `println`, unless you want a blank line between lines.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
try (final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())) {
  System.out.print("Enter the length of the side of your equilateral triangle: ");

  final int side = scanner.nextInt();

  System.out.print("Enter the character you want your triangle to be filled with: ");

  final char character = scanner.next().charAt(0);

  for (int i = 1; i <= side; i++) {
    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(side);

    for (int k = 0; k < (side - i); k++) {
      builder.append(' ');
    }
    System.out.printf(builder.toString());
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      System.out.printf("%s ", character);
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

Please notice the try-with-resources with `Scanner` — only available in from Java 7 (and onwards).

Comment: I'd agree on try-with-resources for all Scanners, *except* a Scanner on `System.in`. You should never close `System.in`.

Comment: @Andreas What's the issue doing that at the end of the application flow? Do you mind elaborating on that?

Comment: This might be correct however it is too complicated for my skill level

Comment: @ɐuıɥɔɐɯ There's no issue when used like that, it's just unnecessary. It's also not an issue if a program *only* accesses System.in using a *single* Scanner. It is however a (workaround) solution for those (misguided) individuals that create multiple Scanners. Anyway, I thought that for *this program*, it was an unnecessary embellishment. I'm good either way. *Godspeed*

Comment: @ɐuıɥɔɐɯ I was wondering: If you bother with a StringBuilder for the indentation, why not use it for the entire line?

Comment: @Andreas Actually, that's a VERY GOOD tip since it will looks always awkward whenever you try to use something different than one space. With the approach you are suggesting is way more easier to space out "correctly" the output in case you want to use even more than one space